# indent in output in python

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to get an appropriate output in pycharm.

The first lines is all good, then suddenly everything is a mess?
using python 3.

not able to post picture...
this is the query i used:

```
for row in c.execute ("SELECT * FROM employee"):
    empno,ename,address,email,phone,role_id,sal = row
    print(
        'Employeenr:', empno,
        '\tName:', ename,
        '\tAddress', address,
        '\tEmail:', email,
        '\tPhone:', phone,
        '\tRole id:', role_id,
        '\tSalary:', sal, 
        sep=' '
    )
```

Comment: What exactly you want to reach?

Comment: What do you mean? 
The first lines in the output is in a good format an easy to read, but then suddenly it is full of indents and looks very messy.

Comment: Can you post example output - 1. what it looks like and 2. what it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue it with `\t`. It just add tab, and this approach will work only if columns content has the same width in all rows. To get nice formatting for the content with variable width, you should set the width for elements directly. For example, using `str().format()` capabilities.

```
for row in c.execute ("SELECT * FROM employee"):
    empno, ename, address, email, phone, role_id, sal = row
    print(
        "Emloyee Nr: {:20} Name: {:20} ... ... Salary: {:8}".format(
            empno, ename, ...,  sal
        )
    )
```